# Can we use an each after a preposition between?

Tags: prepositions

> We shared **between each** students.

Is it correct?

Comment: Do you have any more context for this?

Comment: with a general group like "students" you don't use "between" but "among"

Comment: "between each" works better with positional statements. ex: "There was little space *between each* car."

Comment: In your example, using *between* and *each* seems repetitive. Since you are already saying *between* the students, each student being involved is implied unless you say otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can, but the X in *each X* must be singular, or you have to say *each of the X's*.

> We shared between each *student*.
>
> We shared between each *of the students*

Comment: You can share with each of the students, but you can't share between each student.